# Quantitative research comparing perception of preparation to evaluation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

I am trying to complete my PHD and I am using a survey to determine students' perception of their preparedness to teach and want to compare their answers to what their final summative evaluation says about their ability to teach. I created a questionnaire for the students to answer that reflects each of the areas of the summative evaluation. What statistical test can I use to compare the results? 
I also want to do another analysis and break the data down into the three different category of schools the students teach at to see if that makes a different in their perception of preparation. 
I did a field test to establish a level of construct validity of the questionnaire would that suffice? I only have 114 for the study and don't think breaking the group into 2 groups would give me strong enough numbers for the dissertation study?

Comment: Are you just wondering about the level of correlation / agreement between the survey & the evaluation, or do you think of the eval as the 'gold standard', & want to determine how accurate the student's self-perceptions are? Are you thinking of this as a psychometric / measurement investigation, eg to determine if the areas are coherent, etc?

Comment: My hypotheses are:Differences do not exist between early education teacher interns’ perceptions of their preparedness to teach in kindergarten and their supervisors’ collaborative evaluations of the interns’ ability to teach. 
H1: Differences do not exist between early education teacher interns’ perceptions of their preparedness to teach in primary grades (first through fourth grade) and their supervisors’ collaborative evaluations of the interns’ ability to teach. See if the correlation between intern's perception of how prepared they think they were aligns with the evaluation.